# Application Pool stops-Deploying a Webpart-SP2007

Tags: web-part

I am using sharepoint 2007 and VS 2008. Sometimes after deploying the webpart, the application pool stops and need to start it manually.

I do not know why this is happening?

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do about it. I sometimes have the same problem. Just restart the application pool if this happens.